# Thymeleaf isn't mapping my controller methods to the html templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I'm trying to have objects load in from my database upon loading one of my html templates. Currently, they aren't loading in, and none of my controller methods are working. I can't tell if this is a pom issue or a lack of wiring on my end... Attaching my html, Controller, Application, and pom.

Thanks for your help!

POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sg</groupId>
    <artifactId>SuperHeroSightings</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SuperHeroSightings</name>
    <description>SuperHero Sightings Assessment</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Heroes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Main Body of Page -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row m-4">
                <div class="col text-center border border-dark">
                    <h1><a href="/" class="text-dark">Heroes</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-4 border border-dark">
                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <a href="home.html" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <a href="students" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Search</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                 <div id="tableDiv">

                     <table id="objectTable" class="table table-hover">

                         <tbody id="contentRows"></tbody>
                     </table>
                 </div>

             </div>


            <div class="row m-4 border border-dark">
                <div class="col-3 text-center m-3">
                    <span class="h3">Add Hero</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7 text-center m-3">
                    <form action="addHero" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Name</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input type="text" name="name"
                                       id="name" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="description" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Description</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input type="text" name="description"
                                       id="description" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Superpower" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Superpower</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <select id="superpower" name="superpowerId" class="form-control" >
                                    <option th:each="superpower : ${Superpowers}"
                                            th:value="${superpower.id}"
                                            th:text="${superpower.name}">
                                        Superpower</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="organizations" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Organizations</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <select multiple id="organizations" name="organizationId"
                                        class="form-control" >
                                    <option th:each="organization : ${organizations}"
                                            th:value="${organization.id}"
                                            th:text="${organization.name}">
                                        organization</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Hero</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row m-4 border border-dark">
                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Hero</th>
                             <th>Superpower</th>
                             <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Details</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                              <tr th:each="hero : ${heroes}">
                                   <td th:text='${hero.heroName}'>Hero Name</td>
                                <td th:text="${hero.superPower}">Hero Superpower</td>
                                <td th:text="${hero.heroDescription}">Hero Description</td>
                                <td><a href="#" th:href="@{/courseDetail(id=${course.id})}">Details</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" th:href="@{/editCourse(id=${course.id})}">Update</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" th:href="@{/deleteCourse(id=${course.id})}">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End main body -->

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>;
```

CONTROLLER

```
package com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.controller;

import com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.dao.HeroDao;
import com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.dao.OrganizationDao;
import com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.dao.SuperpowerDao;
import com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.dto.Hero;
import com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.dto.Organization;
import com.sg.SuperHeroSightings.dto.Superpower;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;






/**
 *
 * @author Chelsea, Karma, Mohammed, Patrick
 */
@Controller
public class HeroController {

    @Autowired
    SuperpowerDao superpowerDao;

    @Autowired
    OrganizationDao organizationDao;

    @Autowired
    HeroDao heroDao;
    
    
    
    
 @GetMapping("/heroes")
    public String displayHeroes(Model model) {
        List<Hero> heroes = heroDao.getAllHeroes();
        List<Superpower> superpowers = superpowerDao.getAllSuperpowers();
        List<Organization> organizations = organizationDao.getAllOrganizations();

        model.addAttribute("heroes", heroes);
        model.addAttribute("superpowers", superpowers);
        model.addAttribute("organizations", organizations);

        return "heroes";
    }
```

APPLICATION RUNNER

```
package com.sg.SuperHeroSightings;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SuperHeroSightingsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SuperHeroSightingsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

When I load heroes on my browser I get a file not found error.

UPDATE:
Here is my file structure:
[package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUAXu.png)

[src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFpan.png)

UPDATE:
Here's my application properties with login info redacted.

APPLICATION PROPERTIES

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SuperHeroDB?serverTimezone=America/Chicago&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=[redacted]
spring.datasource.password=[redacted]
spring.profiles.active=database
```

Comment: what happens when you load /heros on browser?

Comment: Also show us your folder structure. Where is your html files located?

Comment: @gtiwari333 just updated the post. thanks for looking it over

Comment: What's in your application.properties ?

Comment: @gtiwari333 just updated app properties

Comment: `@GetMapping("heroes")` change this to `@GetMapping("/heroes")` I believe it must be the problem

Comment: In future, add this `logging.level.root= debug` to your application.properties so that you will get more info when error happens.

Comment: @gtiwari333 adding in the "/" didn't help :/ 

I will add in that logging line, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf wasn't failing me, I was accessing the file directly from my computer rather than going to localhost:8080/heroes in my browser. I'm very new to http requests so forgive me

Comment: Use start.spring.io next time and you won't need to worry about folder structures so much

Comment: @vphilipnyc Thanks for the tip, I'll try that :)